# MySQL calculating sum of time interval proportion overlaps

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a **table** that looks as follow:

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Base   |  Shift |     Start_date      |      End_date       |  Driver |
| ------- | ------ | ------------------- | ------------------- | ------- |
|  390    |   46   | 2017-05-26 10:20:00 | 2017-05-26 11:35:00 |    3    |
|  378    |   46   | 2017-05-26 10:26:00 | 2017-05-26 11:40:00 |    3    |
|  367    |   46   | 2017-05-26 10:05:00 | 2017-05-26 11:30:00 |    3    |
|  350    |   46   | 2017-05-26 13:40:00 | 2017-05-26 14:30:00 |    3    |
|  340    |   45   | 2017-05-25 11:10:00 | 2017-05-25 12:30:00 |    3    |
|  351    |   45   | 2017-05-25 11:10:00 | 2017-05-25 12:30:00 |    3    |
|  656    |   45   | 2017-05-25 09:00:00 | 2017-05-25 10:40:00 |   10    |
|  456    |   45   | 2017-05-25 09:10:00 | 2017-05-25 10:10:00 |   10    |
|   56    |   45   | 2017-05-25 08:00:00 | 2017-05-25 11:50:00 |   10    |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Every shift corresponds to a specific day. I would like to calculate the sum of time interval proportion overlaps for each driver within the same shift. The resulting output should look as below. An example may help in understanding the outcome I am seeking:

- Example 1: driver 3 in shift 46 is serving base 367 and at the same time is serving base 378 for 0.75 of the time and base 390 for 0.82 of the time giving a sum of 1.58. This result indicates that during the time interval driver 3 is serving base 367, is also serving 1.58 other basis concurrently.
- Example 2: driver 10 in shift 45 is serving base 656 and at the same time is serving base 456 for 0.6 of the time and base 56 for 1.0 of the time giving a sum of 1.6.

**Table output:**

```
 ----------------------------------------------------
|  ID   |  Shift | Sum_Overlap_Proportions |  Driver |
| ----- | ------ | ----------------------- | ------- |
|  390  |   46   |       1.853             |    3    |
|  378  |   46   |       1.797             |    3    |
|  367  |   46   |        1.58             |    3    |
|  350  |   46   |           0             |    3    |
|  340  |   45   |           1             |    3    |
|  351  |   45   |           1             |    3    |
|  656  |   45   |         1.6             |   10    |
|  456  |   45   |           2             |   10    |
|   56  |   45   |       0.696             |   10    |
 ----------------------------------------------------
```

It would be great to receive some help with this. I don't have enough SQL skills to tackle this problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: plz arrange the table structure and expected result

Comment: yes sorry, I still haven't figured out how to format tables properly!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: use TIMEDIFF function